# why acf for stationary process is positive semi definite

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I am studying the time series, and the lecture note just state that

For the autocovariance function of a stationary time series one of the property is positive semi definite .

I want to see the proof, but I cant google it

Comment: If you model the acv function by a function which is **not** positive semidefinite, then you will be able to calculate, from that model, some negative variances. You don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

kjetil b halvorsen's [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236330/why-acf-for-stationary-process-is-positive-semi-definite#comment448987_236330) is witty and accurately pointed out the necessity. In any case, this is a routine procedure covered by any good time series textbook. Nevertheless, for the sake of completeness, I am jotting down (paraphrasing) the proof, which basically is the **characterization** of acv functions.

---

**Kolmogorov Consistency Theorem**: Let $\{\mathbf F_{\mathbf t}, ~\mathbf t := \left(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n)^\mathsf T\in \mathbb R^n, ~t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n,~~n\in \mathbb N\right\}$ be the set of finite dimensional distribution functions. $\bf F_t$s can be the distribution functions of a stochastic process if and only if $$\lim_{x_i \to \infty} \mathbf F_{\mathbf t}(\mathbf x) = \mathbf F_{\mathbf t(i)} (\mathbf x(i)),$$ $\mathbf t(i)$ is $\mathbf t$ sans the $i$ th component.

It would take more of a space to derive this and it would, frankly, derail from the matter in hand. Nonetheless, [here](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Esengupta/7360f09/kolmogorov.pdf) is discussed elegantly the proofs both for countable as well as uncountable products.

---

**Theorem**: A function $\gamma: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ is acv function of a stationary time series if and only if it is even and non-negative definite.

I would adumbrate the proof here.

Let $\mathbf a\in \mathbb R^n,~ \mathbf t \in \mathbb Z^n$ and let $\mathbf Z_{\mathbf t} := (X_{t_1}- \mathbb EX_{t_1},\ldots, X_{t_n}- \mathbb EX_{t_n})^\mathsf T. $ Since $\mathbb V(\mathbf a^\mathsf T \mathbf Z_{\mathbf t}) \geqslant 0$ and $\mathbb V(\mathbf a^\mathsf T \mathbf Z_{\mathbf t}) = \mathbf a^\mathsf T \mathbb E \mathbf Z_{\mathbf t}\mathbf Z_{\mathbf t}^\mathsf T\mathbf a, $ one can conclude $[\gamma(t_i-t_j) ]_{i, ~j~=~1}^n$ is non-negative definite.

For the converse, the approach would be to show the existence of a stationary process that is associated with an even non-negative definite function $\gamma(\cdot),$ the latter being the acv of the former. Let $\mathbf K:= [\gamma(t_i-t_j) ]_{i, ~j~=~1}^n.$ For each $n\in \mathbb N, ~\mathbf t\in \mathbb R^n, :t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n,$ let $\mathbf F_{\mathbf t}$ be the distribution function  in $\mathbb R^n$ with characteristic function

$$ \varphi_{\mathbf t}(\mathbf u) := \exp\left(-\mathbf u^\mathsf T\mathbf K\mathbf u/2\right),~\mathbf u\in \mathbb R^n.$$ By assumption, $\mathbf K$ is non-negative and this means $\varphi_{\mathbf t}(\cdot) $ is the characteristic function of an $n$-variate normal distribution with mean $\bf 0$ and covariance matrix $\bf K. $ Now, the critical thing is to note that

$$\varphi_{\mathbf t(i)}(\mathbf u(i)) = \lim_{\mathbf u(i) \to 0}\varphi_{\mathbf t}(\mathbf u) , \forall\mathbf t. $$ This implies $\mathbf F_{\mathbf t}$ is *Kolmogorov* consistent and hence there exists a time series $\langle X_t\rangle$ with the distribution function $\mathbf F_{\mathbf t}.$

---

### Reference:

Time Series: Theory and Methods, *Peter J. Brockwell, Richard A. Davis*, Springer Science & Business Media, 1991.